# How to skip a index in a loop which i get while looping

Tags: c#, performance, loops

**Example: I am verifying some numbers from 1 to 1000 in a for loop.**

Maybe the number 50 is a valid number so all numbers devisible by 50 could be skipped (100, 150, 200, 250, ...) because they are therefore valid too.

So i dont need to verify those numbers again to raise the performance and to shorten my loop processes from 1000 to maybe just 60.

Is there a way to do that?

**Because you asked for the "validation" mechanism:**

I want to validate "amicable" numbers. That is part of a "Project Euler Problem 21". I just want to improve my solution.

Amicable numbers are e.g. 220 and 284 because the sum of its proper divisors of both numbers are the numbers themselve.

Divisors of 220: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110 => sum 284

Divisors of 284: 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142 => sum 220

So both numbers are "amicable" numbers. If I am validating 220 with 284, I dont need to check 284 again and could skip it.

```
List<int> ListOfAmicableNumbers = new List<int>();


for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    if(IsAmicableNumber(i))
    {
        ListOfAmicableNumbers.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a smart mathematical way to skip those values.
Because looping through a List which gets bigger and bigger in every iteration of maybe 1 Million iterations could slow it down again.

Comment: Without seeing what you have tried so far it's difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: Well i had no idea so far to solve this. So I cant offer you a sample :(

Comment: Can you show the verification code - that might help. And what are you criteria for skipping validation?

Comment: You can write a Filter (`DivisbleBy50()`) and use that to `continue;`

Comment: Please post input data examples and expected results/behavior with example data. We have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: @WeißBrot are you trying to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Answer (score 4):

```
int skipValue=50;
for(int i=1; i<=1000;i++)
{
   if(i%skipValue == 0) continue;
   //verification goes here...
}
```

Edit: since you say that you may need more than one skipValue and this list of skipValues is increasing gradually, then try in the following way:

```
List<int> skipValues = new List<int>();//fill them somewhere else...
for(int i=1; i<=1000;i++)
{
   if(skipValues.Any(w => i%w == 0)) continue;
   //verification goes here...
   //after verification you may like to add this value into the list:
   skipValues.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, propably much more cleaner solution,

Comment: This is what I had come up with, but you beat me to it, Zhavat. :)  As an aside... this is a decent prime number detection algorithm, but you MUST start the iteration at value `2` - everything is divisible by `1` and `0` causes a DBZ exception.

Comment: I don't divide by "i", rather I divide by the skipValue ("w") in the list!

Comment: I guess when there is no mathematical solution for that problem, this solution is the smartest so far.